# kafka-apache flink execution log4j error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to run a simple Apache Flink script with Kafka inegration but I keep on having problems with the execution.
The script should read messages coming from a kafka producer, elaborate them, and then send back again, to an other topic, the result of the processing.
I've get this example from here:
http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Simple-Flink-Kafka-Test-td4828.html

The error I have is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:ALL 
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenera‌tor.createJobGraph(S‌​treamingJobGraphGene‌​rator.java:86) 
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.getJobGraph‌​(StreamGraph.java:42‌​9) 
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnviro‌nment.execute(LocalS‌​treamEnvironment.jav‌​a:46)
```

at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnviro‌nment.execute(LocalS‌​treamEnvironment.jav‌​a:33)

This is my code:

```
public class App {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(); 
            Properties properties = new Properties(); 
            properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092"); 

            //properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181"); 
            properties.setProperty("group.id", "javaflink"); 

            DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<String>("test", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));
            System.out.println("Step D"); 
            messageStream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>(){ 

                    public String map(String value) throws Exception { 
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                            return "Blablabla " +  value; 
                    } 
            }).addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer010("localhost:9092", "demo2", new SimpleStringSchema())); 
            env.execute(); 
      }
}
```

These are the `pom.xml` dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-java_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

What could cause this kind of error?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: It is not an error. It is just a warning. Your job should work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by the mixture of different Flink versions you have defined in your `pom.xml`. In order to run this program, it should be enough to include the following dependencies:

```xml
<!-- Streaming API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- In order to execute the program from within your IDE -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Kafka connector dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Great to hear. If my answer solved your problem, then you can accept it so that others see that this solves this problem.